# How do I create a new table using a value from another table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to create a new table using SQLite. This new table should be named Layer12_Comment_Phrases, and it should get that 'Layer12' from another table named 'Layers' in the 'Internal' column. Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO Layers (User, FKOfacilityName, Internal, MultiSelect, FeatureAddable, FeatureDeletable, FeatureEditable, FeatureMovable, EnableLoadLast, EnableTimeSheet, AllowCommentEdits, ShapeType, IsInitiallyVisible, Proj4, ProjectionUnits, LinearUnits, ArealUnits, Order_By, MinZoomLevel, MaxZoomLevel, LabelsEnabled, EnableLoadLastComments)
SELECT User, FKOfacilityName, 'Layer'||(COALESCE(MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(Internal,6) AS INTEGER)),0)+1), MultiSelect, FeatureAddable, FeatureDeletable, FeatureEditable, FeatureMovable, EnableLoadLast, EnableTimeSheet, AllowCommentEdits, ShapeType, IsInitiallyVisible, Proj4, ProjectionUnits, LinearUnits, ArealUnits, (COALESCE(MAX(Order_By),0)+100), MinZoomLevel, MaxZoomLevel, LabelsEnabled, EnableLoadLastComments
FROM Layers
ORDER BY Internal DESC
LIMIT 1;

CREATE TABLE ['Layer'||(COALESCE(MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(Internal,6) AS INTEGER)),0)+1)||'_Comment_Phrases'] (Phrase TEXT, Order_By Integer);
```

Everything in the first part of the query works, it creates a new row in the 'Layers' table and the 'Internal' column is properly updated. There are currently 11 rows in that table, so the new one added is going to have the value Layer12. Each previous value in that column has a similar name: Layer11, Layer10, etc. However when creating the table I get a table named:

```
'Layer'||(COALESCE(MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(Internal,6) AS INTEGER)),0)+1)||'_Comment_Phrases']
```

instead of

```
Layer12_Comment_Phrases
```

So, how can I update my CREATE TABLE query so that the new table is correctly named "Layer12_Comment_Phrases"

I apologize if this question doesn't make sense or is blatantly obvious. I'm very new to coding as a whole and I'm not sure how to properly communicate my questions yet.

Comment: Are you running a stored procedure? I don't think table name can be dynamic. Probably need to use code (C+, PHP, vb.net, VBA, etc) to pull value from the newly created record in Layers table and run SQL statement constructed in code. Why are you creating a table for each Internal field value? This does not appear to be normalized data schema.

Comment: I think you have an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You shouldn't be creating new tables that are copies of other tables but with a different set of rows. Instead, create *one* table but add another column to indicate which set the row belongs to - the "12" in your example , perhaps defined as `layer int not null`, maybe even a foreign key.